# Auto close windows module failed!

Tags: power-windows

Bought new autoclose windows and when tested it continues to only close windows for 3 seconds.

The module is designed to close one window at a time and any resistance if felt, it will stop at that moment. Same is for other windows.

However, on testing, all windows works only for 3 seconds.

Inside PCB board is attached herewith. Please kindly help which component is responsible for detecting the resistance of the windows.[image]

Comment: The orange potentiometer ... is that glue on it or is it melted? It looks deformed.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Trimpots (trimmer potentiometers) are usually factory adjusted and then glued so that the end user and/or vibration do not change their setting. It looks OK IMHO.

Comment: Are you testing that module by locking the car? Are you sure the car electronics aren't cutting the power after 3s of being locked?

Comment: BTW, the component you've asked for is probably that zig-zag wire on the bottom left acting as a current sense resistor.

Comment: RaphaelP how that particular component actually sense the current going to the window power motor to sense any resistance and stop the motor??Also, that little potential is ok. It comes from company.

Comment: IF my last comment is right, then that piece of wire has a small but measurable resistance. When the window movement is blocked, it's electric motor stalls and the circuit current goes up. When the current goes up, so does the voltage drop across that "resistor". The module compares that voltage to some internal value, which is probably adjusted by that potentiometer. It is also probably one of the reasons the module only closes one window at a time, since the resistor is shared across all 4 relay circuits. Depending on how the module works, the resistor sits either connected to GND/0V or 12V.

Comment: @RaphaelP that resistor will for sure be connected to one or the other...

Comment: 1. That resistor show buzzing sound when test with multimeter which means resistance is very low. 2. That resistor is shared among the 4 relays. 3. That resistor is a supply wire for each relays, meaning, always 12 v regardless of the auto close function is activated or not. 4. What is the relationship between resistor length and current flowing through it? 5. What if I try to extend its length longer??